# Java equivalent of Spanner numeric data type

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I am getting `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid code: UNRECOGNIZED` while trying to access a spanner NUMERIC column from Java application using spanner repository.
I am getting the above error .I have tried with Long,float and bigdecimal  on the entity.Can anyone share the thoughts on this  .

Answer (score 1):

`NUMERIC` data types in Cloud Spanner should be used with `BigDecimal`.

Support for the `NUMERIC` data type was introduced in Cloud Spanner Java client library in version 1.59.0. The most probable reason for this error is that you are using an older version of the client library. Your question mentions that you tried it 'on the entity', which might indicate that you are using Hibernate.

Could you please share more information about your specific situation, which should at least include:

- Any relevant frameworks you are using (Hibernate, Spring, ...)
- Versions of these frameworks
- Version of the Cloud Spanner Java client library

Please also always include:

- A snippet of your actual code, or otherwise a small code sample that will actually reproduce the problem.
- The entire (anonymized) stacktrace of your error, instead of only the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric will refer to BigDecimal in java. You could always check from Spring Data Spanner framework code that contains all datatype mapping from java to spanner.

SpannerTypeMapper.java

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-data-spanner/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/data/spanner/core/convert/SpannerTypeMapper.java

Answer (score 0):

this is because of older version of spanner, numeric type was introduced later, you might be using bigdecimal which is not a part of TYPECODE.class

BigDecimal works perfectly fine with NUMERIC fields.

TYPE_CODE_UNSPECIFIED(0),
BOOL(1),
INT64(2),
FLOAT64(3),
TIMESTAMP(4),
DATE(5),
STRING(6),
BYTES(7),
ARRAY(8),
STRUCT(9),
NUMERIC(10)

if your TYPECODE.class has all of these. if not Please update dependency and your issue must be resolved.